# How to get a value in my input form in my controller Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Hello i want to récupurate a login and password value in my form

```
 <form action="#"  modelAttribute="authentification"  th:action="@{/user/add}"    method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">prenom</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="prenom"  name="prenom" placeholder="prenom">

</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"   placeholder="Password">
</div>



<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Nouveau Client je M'inscris</button>
</form>
```

exactly i want to recover value to my inputs password and prenom and i dont found the good method to do this

Controller :

```
@Autowired
UserImplementation ui;

@PostMapping("/add")
public String authentification(  Model m ,@PathVariable final String nom)
{

List<Utilisateur> user;

 user =ui.getuser();
m.addAttribute("Utilisateur", ui.getuser());

for(Utilisateur u : user)
{
    if(u.getPrenom().equals(nom))
    {
        return"clienthome";
    }
    else {
        int i =10;
        m.addAttribute("i", i);
        return"index";
    }

}
return "index";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting wrong parameters in your `PostMapping` method `authentification`. You could do the following to be able to obtain the HTML input data in your controller method.

Here I assume your `prenom` and `password` attributes are contained in an object named `User`.

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public String authentification(@ModelAttribute("authentification") User user) {
    // Your mentioned business logic
}
```

If your `prenom` and `password` attributes are not contained in an object and are simply just `String`s you are trying to obtain, then you can do the following:

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public String authentification(@RequestParam String prenom, @RequestParam String password) {
    // Your mentioned business logic
}
```

The names of the 2 strings `prenom` and `password` have to be equal to the specific attribute's `name` tag in your HTML file (i.e. `name="prenom"` and `name="password"`), or else you will receive `null` as argument for the unequally named attribute in your controller method.

If you want to bind the HTML name to the HTML attribute, but want to name your controller method parameter(s) something different, then the `@RequestParam` annotation provides a way to specify the expected HTML parameter name to bind it to. E.g. `@RequestParam("prenom") String somethingDifferent` will bind `somethingDifferent` to the HTML attribute named `prenom`.